# Excel: if cell contains text, then add multiple criteria using if function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone help me with this formula in MS Excel?

If Cell "C2" has the text "Sell" then the formula will be "F2-H2"
or Cell "C2" has the text "Buy" then the formula will be "H2-F2"

I want to use two formulas together in the same cell.

[image: View Image for reference]

Comment: `=IF(C2="Sell",F2-H2,H2-F2)*100000`

Comment: The formula is working perfectly, but I want 1 more thing to do. If there is nothing in the cell then nothing will show in the result. Currently, it's by default showing 0.

Comment: `=IF(C2="","",IF(C2="Sell",F2-H2,H2-F2)*100000)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem has been perfectly solved by @Scott Craner, I just want to make the number of replies become 1.

```
=IF(C2="","",SUM(-1^(C2="Buy")*IF({1,0},F2,-H2))*10^5)
```

or

```
=IF(C2="","",(MAX(F2:H2)-MIN(F2:H2))*10^5)
```

Comment: For this, I am grateful to you. Thank you for giving me another solution & your time.